# orderBy attributes of another table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

On my website I allow users to upload images/like images/favorite images/etc.

Therefore, I've got a table for images, likes, favorites, etc.

I can get and display these images just fine, and sort them as I like

```
$images = Images::orderBy('id', 'desc')->Paginate(50);
```

I can also display how much likes/favorites an image has.

```
$favCount = Favorite::where('image_id', $image->id)->count();
```

However, what would I do to sort images by, say, how many favorites it they have? I have a favorite model and an image model but I'm not sure how I would go about it.

**EDIT:**

Current query for the answer given:

```
$images = Images::join('favorites', 'favorites.image_id', '=', 'images.id')
->select('images.link', DB::raw('count(favorites.id) as favs'))
->orderBy('favs', 'desc')
->groupBy('images.link')
->take(10)
->get();
```

And the error is:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'images' in 'field list' (SQL: select `images`, count(favorites.id) as favs from `images` inner join `favorites` on `favorites`.`image_id` = `images`.`id` group by `images`.`link` order by `favs` desc limit 10)

Comment: Did you try it with `DB` as I did? I think the error comes from `Images::raw()`. Try replacing `Images::raw` by `DB::raw()`. Or do all the query with `DB` as I did. And see the results. Please.

Comment: Ah, you were right. Sorry, this is my first time using raw expressions. Still got an error, though. The new query and error will be in the main post. Thanks for helping me out, though!

Comment: In your table `images` if you have a property `link` or `name`. Try `select('link', DB::raw('count(favorites.id) as favs'))`. It seems you don't have property `images` in your table `images`. Can you try it all with `DB` as I did and see if it works ?

Comment: Ok I tried switching out images.link with images.title, and I'm able to print out a list of image titles with {{ $image->title }} in my foreach loop in my blade template, however I can't print any other attribute, such as {{ $image->description }}. Ideally I'd like to be able to get all attributes of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user query builder like this:

```
$images = DB::table('images')
->join('favorites', 'favorites.image_id', '=', 'images.id')
->select('images.link', DB::raw('count(favourites.id) as favs'))
->orderBy('favs', 'desc') //order in descending order
->groupBy('images.link')
->take(10) //limit the images to Top 10 favorite images.
->get();
```

The same could be accomplished with Eloquent.

Comment: the line ->select('images.link', Images::raw('count(favourites.id) as favs') gives me the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'. If I remove that line and the lines after, and I only have the join and the get, I don't have an error. (it returns all the images with favorites)

Comment: nvm it was missing a closing bracket. Now I get strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: What line produces that error? This code works fine on my computer (after fixing the missing bracket).

Comment: Not sure. But here's the error log: http://paste.ofcode.org/RBG2sPHUqmrSmWrkbAVRS8

Comment: I also pasted my query in the main post

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be.

```
$images = Images::join('favorites', 'favorites.image_id', '=', 'images.id')
->orderBy('favs', 'desc')
->groupBy('images.link')
->take(10)
->get(['images.link', DB::raw('count(favorites.id) as favs')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I still get the same error as up top, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'images.link' in 'field list'

Comment: Hey Felix. `link` is just an attribute I made up. Put your own `Image` model attributes. Please. Thank you Patel for joining.

Comment: Ok I tried switching out images.link with images.title, and I'm able to print out a list of image titles with {{ $image->title }} in my foreach loop in my blade template, however I can't print any other attribute, such as {{ $image->description }}. Ideally I'd like to be able to get all attributes of the table.

Comment: Add it in the select() like `select('images.title', 'images.description', 'images.anything_else_you_want_to_display', DB::raw('count(favourites.id) as favs'))`

Answer (score 0):

> Sorting can be done based on the request.

```
    if($request->sort){
         $events->join('event_packages', 'event_packages.ev_event_id', '=', 'ev_events.id')
            ->select('ev_events.*', DB::raw('min(event_packages.price_per_ticket) as price_per_ticket'))
            ->groupBy('ev_events.id');
            if($request->sort == 1){
                $events->orderBy('price_per_ticket', 'asc');
            }else{
                $events->orderBy('price_per_ticket', 'desc');
            }
    }else{
        $events->orderBy('id','desc');
    }
```